# How to install library to external maven repository

Tags: maven

in your company we are using archiva as our maven repository. How I can install there some library which is not mavenized remotely ? In my local repository I can do something like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -D groupId=cz.i -D artifactId=sql-processor \
                         -D version=1.0 -D packaging=jar \
                         -D file=~/programy/cro/lib/sql-processor.jar
```

When I want to add some maven project to our archiva, I can run this command: `mvn:deploy`. But I have no idea how to install just library there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closer than you think - just replace `install:install-file` with `deploy:deploy-file` and add a bit of sugar, as can be [read here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html):

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=cz.i \
  -DartifactId=sql-processor \
  -Dversion=1.0 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=~/programy/cro/lib/sql-processor.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=<id-to-archiva-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml> \
  -Durl=<your-archiva-URL>
```

As you - correctly - state, this should only be used for "non-mavenized" external artifacts, otherwise `mvn deploy` is the way to go.

Cheers,